# C++: Listing the permutations of a string

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, permutation

I would like to ask all my fellow programmers regarding only **efficiency**. I am currently solving problems that could be asked in job interviews and I've come across with the famous permutations of a **string**. The code I've written below might be the most common thing in programming history, however, I do not know it's status since I haven't checked for any solution.

Long story would the short the program I've coded below be a suitable solution? Or can it be made even more efficient. Asking because if I came across one day I would like to be sure that I've implement one of the best approaches for this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fac(int num)
{
    int result=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=num;i++)
        result*=i;
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string str="abcd";
    int limit=fac(str.size());
    int mod=str.size();
    for(int i=0;i<limit;i++){
        swap(str[i%mod],str[(i+1)%mod]);
        cout<<str<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You know about `std::next_permutation`, right?

Comment: Yeah I do. But did not refer to it since its an std library, not a solution I've come up with

Comment: If you're not interested in people correctly telling you not to reinvent the wheel, then this belongs on [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of SO.

Comment: I am soooo thankful I've never had to go through one of those interviews, and the nutty questions they're liable to ask. That's an advantage to a history of consulting and/or teaching. Your reputation precedes you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the solution by using a `std::map`. Don't think it is **that inefficient;**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int fac(int num)
{
    int result=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=num;i++)
        result*=i;
    return result;
}
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string str="aabb";
    int limit=fac(str.size());
    int mod=str.size();
    std::map<string,bool>T;
    vector<string>permutations;
    for(int i=0;i<limit;i++){
        if(T[str]==0){
            permutations.push_back(str);
            T[str]=1;
        }
        swap(str[i%mod],str[(i+1)%mod]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<permutations.size();i++)
        cout<<permutations[i]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're willing to use the standard library, then why not use `std::next_permutation`? I don't get it.

Comment: There's value in implementing your own solution, it's good practice. Of course, if you want to "get stuff done" and be more productive use the Standard Library.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't handle duplicated letters within the string, e.g. `"aaabbb"`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll be checking it! By the way, any suggestions :D?

Answer (score 1):

You could use recursion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void swap(char &first, char &second) {
    char tmp = first;
    first = second;
    second = tmp;
}

void enumPermutations(string &p, int m)
{
    if (m == p.size() - 1)
        cout << p << endl;
    else
        for (int j = m; j < p.size(); j++) {
            swap(p[j], p[m]);
            enumPermutations(p, m+1);
            swap(p[j], p[m]);
        }
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string str = "abcd";
    enumPermutations(str, 0);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

(compiled and tested in Visual Studio).

Comment: Probably slower but good to know options (esp. for interview prep)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is **NO**. You should not worry about the efficiency of any proposed solution until you know that it works.  And this one does not work.

The following demonstrates that fact.

```
ben-tillys-macbook-pro:ton btilly$ cat foo.cc
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fac(int num)
{
    int result=1;
    for(int i=1;i<=num;i++)
        result*=i;
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    string str="abcd";
    int limit=fac(str.size());
    int mod=str.size();
    for(int i=0;i<limit;i++){
        swap(str[i%mod],str[(i+1)%mod]);
        cout<<str<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
ben-tillys-macbook-pro:ton btilly$ g++ foo.cc
ben-tillys-macbook-pro:ton btilly$ ./a.out | wc
      24      24     120
ben-tillys-macbook-pro:ton btilly$ ./a.out | sort -u | wc
      12      12      60
ben-tillys-macbook-pro:ton btilly$ ./a.out | grep bdc
ben-tillys-macbook-pro:ton btilly$
```

Comment: I've corrected the code. Check my answer and thanks for the contribution